# Can make the proxy settings invisible when I share my internet connection via wifi?

Tags: ubuntu, android, proxy, ad-hoc-network

This is probably a long shot...

I have an HTC Desire and frustratingly found out after I got it that it doesn't support network proxy settings.

We have a wireless network at my office that uses a proxy.

My desktop at work runs ubuntu.

I was wondering if the following set up would work:

1. Plug a USB Wireless adapter into the desktop that has a working internet connection using the proxy.
2. Setup the wireless adapter as an ad-hoc network
3. Share the internet connection over the ad-hoc network.
4. Make it so that the use of the proxy is invisible to users of the shared network connection.
5. Connect the Android phone to the ad-hoc wireless network and utilise the internet connection.

My question is this:  Is this possible or should I give up now and not even try?

I think I can handle steps 1, [2, 3](http://bigbrovar.wordpress.com/2009/01/17/share-you-internet-wirelessly-on-ubuntu/) and 5. I just have no idea if step 4 even makes sense, let alone is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be possible.  You would probably need to setup a proxy server on your ubuntu system like squid.  Configure the squid proxy to work in [interception mode](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InterceptionProxy), and point your squid proxy on the Ubuntu system at the [upstream proxy](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CacheHierarchy).

If you could get whoever is running the wifi/upstream-proxy to set it transparent then you wouldn't need to do any of this hackery.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The upstream proxy is out of my hands but I may be able to talk the guy who set up the wifi into letting me tinker with it.  I'll have a go at researching the 'transparent' wifi option.  

Much appreciated.